# How do I combine a frame (mdframed) and title (titlesec)

Tags: lyx, titlesec, mdframed

Assume that I have a frame:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{aaa}{
        linecolor=black!50,
        backgroundcolor=Honeydew3!80,
        roundcorner = 6pt,
        fontcolor = black,
        shadow=true,
        shadowsize=3pt,
        shadowcolor=Honeydew3!20,
        userdefinedwidth = 0.5\columnwidth,
        outerlinewidth = 0.3}
```

and I want to put it at title format, e,g,:

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large}{\thesection}{0.2cm}{\begin{aaa}}[\end{aaa}]
```

This is doesn't working. This is what I get:
[image]

Do you know why and how can I solve it?

Here is the complete code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Yehuda CLM}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}.}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ,framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{aaa}{
linecolor=black!50,
backgroundcolor=Honeydew3!80,
roundcorner = 6pt,
fontcolor = black,
shadow=true,
shadowsize=3pt,
shadowcolor=Honeydew3!20,
userdefinedwidth = 0.5\columnwidth,
outerlinewidth = 0.3}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large}{\thesection}{0.2cm}{\begin{mdframed}[style=partl]}[\end{mdframed}]

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]%

\section{Hello}
\end{english}%

\end{document}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Please, make the snippet into a compilable example.

Comment: @egreg - I put an example - but it won't compile... :-(

Answer (score 2):

I can propose this, which relies on `pstricks`. I suggest using the `wrap` style, so the interlining between 1st and 2nd line of section doesn't change:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mdframed, framed}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{pstricks, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[wrap]{\Large}{}{0cm}{\psshadowbox*[linecolor=Honeydew4, fillcolor=Honeydew3!80, shadowcolor=Honeydew3!20]{\thesection.\enspace#1\bigstrut[b]}}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[wrap]{\Large}{}{0cm}{\psshadowbox*[linecolor=Honeydew4, fillcolor=Honeydew3!80, shadowcolor=Honeydew3!20]{#1\bigstrut[b]}}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you can do without a shadow, you can obtain almost the same result with a simple `\fcolorbox`:

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large}{}{0cm}{\fcolorbox{Honeydew4}{Honeydew3!80}{\thesection.\enspace#1\bigstrut[b]}}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[runin]{\Large}{}{0cm}{\fcolorbox{Honeydew4}{Honeydew3!80}{#1\bigstrut[b]}}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all -Thank you!! But can you do this with rounded corners? (and how you change the size of border line?) BTW - Why do you need the `pstricks`? where do you use it?

Comment: How do I remove the number of the section? I.e. I use unnumbered sections... It doesn't work for me: at the first method: https://imgur.com/a/UxcBkB5  and at the second: https://imgur.com/lt2BibU 

Why it doesn't working?

Comment: @heblyx: I've posted a second code (for both methods) which uses the `numberless` key of titlesec. Is it OK now?

Comment: No... :-( It's still doing the same problem :( https://imgur.com/a/tmep6qz

Comment: Here is the code: https://anotepad.com/notes/chjq5t

Comment: I'm wondering whether it is a problem in relation with right-to-left languages. Could you test your code just using english and Latin alphabet, just to see what happens?

Comment: Still doesn't work... :-(

Comment: But just the code I posted works?

Comment: No... :-( I put the commands of titlesec at my document and it doesn't work...

Comment: Try just the code first. There's probably something in your code that interacts with what I propose. The problem is to find what.

Comment: I try to put your code and this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/l3OJrAv

Comment: Are you using a script for Hebrew?

Comment: Yes, because I'm writing at Hebrew...

Comment: I guessed so, but can you try just with a Latin script, to see whether it is a problem with left-to-right languages or something with your installation

Comment: How I'm doing it? (At lyx) I'm trying and it's still the same result...

Comment: I don't know  LyX, but the simplest would be to use a dedicated TeX editor copy the whole code Iposted, and see what happens when you compile. If you don't have  a TeX editor already  installed, download TeXmaker or TeXstudio.

Comment: I have TeX editor, so copy your code?

Comment: Yes, and see if it compiles fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile it... `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630)
entering extended mode
(boxt.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \usepackage
               [utf8]{inputenc}
? `

Comment: (I'm using TeXworks)

Comment: @Bernard Hi, can you edit your code? There is a out \documentclass{article}. :-) Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano: No problem, please do.

Comment: @Bernard Absolut nicht :-) Maybe I did it only once to edit your answer but it won't repeat again. For me it's a form of respect for good users.